# Sorting records in a CSV file

Tags: node.js, typescript, csv, file

Tell me how you can sort records in CSV files using typescript + node js. Sort by Id.
The number of records in files can be up to 1 million.

Here's an example of file entries:

> [Blockquote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7FMl.png)

Comment: Sort by what : by a field's string value, [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) comparing strings using the default compare function of `string[]` `.sort()`? And what about after they're sorted? Write out to a sibling file? We need more criteria to help you. Are you needing help with the JavaScript approach, or conceptual help because you don't have enough memory allocated to parse and hold the data in memory at once?

Comment: Sorting by string value - Id. After sorting, you need to write to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a conceptual solution:

1. Create a new SQLite db with a table having the appropriate schema for your columns
2. Stream the data from the source CSV file, reading one line at a time: parse and insert the data from the line into the db table from the previous step
3. Create the output CSV file and append the header line
4. Iterate over the db table entries in the desired sort order, one at a time: convert each entry back into a CSV line in the correct column order, and then append the line to the CSV file in the previous step
5. Cleanup: (Optionally validate your new CSV file, and then) delete the SQLite db

If you can fit the entire parsed CSV data in memory at once, you push each line into an array instead of using a db. Then you just sort the array in-place and iterate its elements.